# Socket programming accept() in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Okay I'm brand new to socket programming and my program is not behaving like I'd expect it to.  In all the examples that I see of socket programming they use accept() and all the code after assumes that a connection has been made.

But my accept() is called as soon as I start the server.  Is this supposed to happen?  Or is the server supposed to wait for a connection before executing the rest of the program?

EDIT: Oops I forgot to mention it is a TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after.

http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm#Accept

The main concept within winsocket programming is you're working with either blocking or non blocking sockets. Most of the time if you're using blocking sockets you can query the sockets recieve set to see if any call would result in your call to the routine being blocked..

For starting off with this UDP is easier considering its a datagram protocol. TCP on the other hand is a streaming protocol. So it's easier to think in regards to blocks of data that is sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

For a server, you:

- Create the socket - `socket()`.
- Bind it to an address.
- You enter a loop in which you:

  - Listen for connection attempts
  - Accept and process them

It is not clear from your description whether you are doing all those steps.

There are multiple options for the *'process them'* phase, depending on whether you plan to have a single-threaded single process handle one request before processing the next, or whether you plan to have a multi-threaded single process, with one thread accepting requests and creating other threads to do the processing (while the one thread waits for the next incoming connection), or whether you plan to have the process fork with the child processing the new request while the parent goes back to listening for the next request.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to enter your acceptance loop after you have started listening for connections.  Use `select()` to detect when a pending client connection is ready to be accepted, then call `accept()` to accept it.